# Dspace: Internal System error after installation

Tags: dspace

I have successfully installed Dspace v.4.2 on Windows Laptop but I get this message on JSP Interface under the green bar "Dspace at my university":
{{Internal System Error 
The system has experienced an internal error. Please try to do what you were doing again, and if the problem persists, please contact us so we can fix the problem}} as well as the default introductory text on XMLUI doesn't appear.
How can I fix this problem and what the cause of that.

Comment: When you see Internal System errors being displayed in the web user interface, a corresponding stacktrace should normally be logged in your dspace log files /dspace/log. Could you go in there and post the corresponding stacktrace/detailed error message?

Comment: Hi Bram, 2014-08-30 03:35:21,809 ERROR org.dspace.app.xmlui.aspect.discovery.SidebarFacetsTransformer @ anonymous:session_id=0B68D572CE1603C50D5E33DAC9C23188:ip_addr=127.0.0.1:Error in Discovery while setting up date facet range:date facet\colon; dateIssued.year
org.dspace.discovery.SearchServiceException: Server at http://localhost:8080/solr/search returned non ok status:404, message:Not Found

Comment: at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)

Comment: ERROR cocoon.handled  - Failed to process pipeline

Comment: AXException: An error was encountered while processing the 'aspect.general.PageNotFoundTransformer' Wing based component: org.dspace.app.xmlui.aspect.general.PageNotFoundTransformer
org.apache.cocoon.ResourceNotFoundException: Page cannot be found

Comment: as @pnbecker mentions below, it is very likely that the errors are related to the separate SOLR webapp being unavailable.

Especially the error you posted "org.dspace.discovery.SearchServiceException: Server at localhost:8080/solr/search returned non ok status:404, message:Not Found " points in this direction.

Answer (score 2):

it seems like a Solr's problem.
A solution to your problem is to copy the folder
"[dspace-installation-directory]\webapps\solr" to "C:\Program Files\Apache
Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat (your version)\webapps" (or wherever is
the Tomcat's installation directory).

Then you can test if Solr is "working" @

www.hostname.com:8080/solr/

try this

Answer (score 0):

Bram's question is the right way to find the reason of the problem. This is the only way to investigate and solve it.

Nevertheless there are two common problems you could check first:

- Is your database running and is DSpace able to connect to it? You can use the script in [dspace-install]/bin/dspace under Unix/Linux or [dspace-install]/bin/dspace.bat under Windows. Add 'test-database' as first argument to the script to test the database connection.
- DSpace comes with several webapps that can be deployed to your Servlet Container. While there are some webapps you will only need if you need specific features, the SOLR webapp should always be deployed. SOLR is used by DSpace for search, discovery and other features that will be used in other webapps like dspace-oai, dspace-jspui or dspace-xmlui. There are several ways to get a list of all deployed and running webapps from your Servlet Container, please consider the documentation of your Servlet container. Another way is to try to connect to the solr-webapp. If you do the later please have in mind that for security reasons dspace-solr will be only reachable over the loopback device, this means by using 127.0.0.1 or another loopback address to connect to it.

Hope that helps?
Regards